# jquery ajax setTimeout 0 ms

Tags: jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-does-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-help)

Reading jQuery 1.8 source,

WHY does it do setTimeout with 0 ms delay ?
(instead of just executing the callback ?)

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8.0/src/ajax/xhr.js#L196

```
                if ( !s.async ) {                       
                    callback();
                } else if ( xhr.readyState === 4 ) {


                    // (IE6 & IE7) if it's in cache and has been
                    // retrieved directly we need to fire the callback

         //-------->// WHY do setTimeout with 0 ms delay ?
                    setTimeout( callback, 0 );
                } else {
                    handle = ++xhrId;
```

Comment: @Strelok not really a duplicate IMHO, although it is related.  In this instance it's needed to maintain the functional contract with the programmer, and not to work around any particular issue.

Comment: ah, actually it's to work around a peculiarity of IE6/7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a workaround for a peculiarity of IE6 and IE7 which can retrieve an AJAX result from cache without firing the `XMLHTTPRequest` callback, immediately setting its `readyState` property to `4`, instead.

However the API contract for `$.ajax` requires that it return immediately for an asynchronous request (i.e. without calling the programmer-supplied callbacks).

Hence `$.ajax` call tests for those cached results, and then fakes the required asynchronous callback using `setTimeout`.

The `$.ajax` call completes, and as soon as the browser re-enters its event processing loop it'll find the (immediately expired) timer event and call its callbacks.

Comment: so without doing setTimeout, current (executing?) function will be stopped to execute callback()? 
when you said current function, does it mean the function that encloses the if statement (which is #send() )

Comment: @portoalet I've rewritten this answer almost entirely to try to make it clearer.

Comment: makes more sense after reading john resig article http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that setTimeout adds the function to the browser event queue so it will only be invoked after the preceding events in the queue have been handled, allowing the rest of the function that sets the timeout to finish execution.

Comment: what does "remove the function from the execution queue" mean?

Comment: I don't understand why this is getting up voted.  What is this so-called "execution queue" and why do you think it's possible to remove things from it?

Comment: "execution queue" might not be the best expression for what I mean. I mean the function is called asynchronously and must wait until the next possible execution point, allowing the current function to finish. Maybe invocation queue is a better expression

Comment: that would make some sense if you had written "event queue" rather than "execution queue", except that it's in no way possible for `setTimeout` to _remove_ something from the event queue.

Comment: Poor formulation because of trying to be too quick. I rephrased.